# Dependence of wireless channel capacity on the system operating temperature

Tags: wireless

Does system temperature have any effect on the achievable channel capacity (channel capacity modelled using Shannon's theorem)? If the temperature is tripled or doubled, will it affect the channel capacity?

Comment: Well ambient temperature is about 300 kelvin and if this doubled to 600 kelvin then solder would melt.

Comment: I'm sure it does...eventually because ionization and plasma of the air

Comment: You should be able to plot the thermal noise floor (ie, what is usually thought of as -174 dBm/Hz) against *absolute* temperature yourself.  But remember the large offset from absolute to familiar temperatures - you're likely to see equipment issues more than theoretical ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system temperature would directly affect the thermal noise power, which in turn would affect the signal-to-noise ratio and hence your capacity. As a starting point, you can use the following expression to calculate the thermal noise power

$$
\begin{align}
N &= K_{b} T B F \\[5pt] 
N &- \text{Noise power (W)} \\
K_{b} &- \text{Boltzmann's constant} = 1.3807 \times 10^{-23} ~\text{JK}^{-1} \\
T &- \text{System temperature (K)} \\
B &- \text{Bandwidth (Hz)} \\
F &- \text{Noise figure}
\end{align}$$
where all the terms are in scalar form (not in dB). Naturally, there could be additional noise effects apart from the thermal noise power.

Comment: So, as the system temperature increases, the SNR decreases and hence the capacity decreases. Understood now!